Multiple commands produce Xcode -15
I'm trying to use paytm_allinone_react-native library but It's throwing Error "Multiple commands produce".  Could you please suggestion me how can I fix this.
Multiple commands produce
Target 'paytm_allinone_react-native' (project 'Pods') has copy command from ‘/PATH/node_modules/paytm_allinone_react-native/ios/AppInvokeSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/AppInvokeSDK.framework/Headers/AppInvokeSDK.h' to 'PATH/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytm_allinone_react-native/paytm_allinone_react_native.framework/Headers/AppInvokeSDK.h'](PATH/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytm_allinone_react-native/paytm_allinone_react_native.framework/Headers/AppInvokeSDK.h')    

Target 'paytm_allinone_react-native' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/PATH/node_modules/paytm_allinone_react-native/ios/AppInvokeSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/AppInvokeSDK.framework/Headers/AppInvokeSDK.h' to 'PATH/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytm_allinone_react-native/paytm_allinone_react_native.framework/Headers/AppInvokeSDK.h'](PATH/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytm_allinone_react-native/paytm_allinone_react_native.framework/Headers/AppInvokeSDK.h')

System:
  OS: macOS 14.4.1
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
  Memory: 62.13 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 22.0.0
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.22
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 10.5.0
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.04.29.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.4
      - iOS 17.4
      - macOS 14.4
      - tvOS 17.4
      - visionOS 1.1
      - watchOS 10.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.3 AI-233.14808.21.2331.11709847
  Xcode:
    version: 15.3/15E204a
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java: Not Found
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.3.1
    wanted: 18.3.1
  react-native:
    installed: 0.74.1
    wanted: 0.74.1
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "react-native": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false

